# Are there any advantages in using Indexes on tables in Hadoop over Oracle?

Tags: oracle, apache, hadoop, indexing, hive

I need to compare the Indexing in Oracle Vs Hadoop(Hive). Up till now, I could find two major indexing techniques in Hive i.e. COMPACT INDEXING and BITMAP INDEXING. I could check out the performance difference of COMPACT INDEXING in Hive compared to Oracle. I would need to understand more use cases / scenarios of using Bitmap Indexing in Hive. Also, need to know if Hive supports Reverse Key Indexes , Ascending and Descending Indexes like Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

- YES their is significant advantages in using index in HIVE over
  oracle, keeping in mind that HIVE is suitable for Large data sets and
  yet their are developments in making HIVE a real time data
  warehousing tool.
- One use case in which BITMAP indexing can be used is where table with
  columns having distinct values and obviously it should be a large
  table (you will get better results if table is large, do not test
  with small tables).
- As of now HIVE Supports only two indexing techniques COMPACT and
  BITMAP for explicitly creating indexes.
- Also Indexes in Hive are not recommended (although you can create as
  per your use case), the reason for this is [ORC Format](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC).
- ORC format has build in Indexes which allow the format to skip blocks of
  data during read, they also support Bloom filters index. Together
  this pretty much replicates what Hive Indexes did and they do it
  automatically in the data format without the need to manage an
  external table ( which is essentially what happens in indexes).
- I would suggest you to rather spend your time to properly setup the
  ORC tables.

  also read this great post about [hive indexing](https://acadgild.com/blog/indexing-in-hive/).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning built in Indexes in ORC format.

Answer (score 0):

hive is data warehousing tool that runs on hadoop. inbuilt it has mapreduce capacity for hive queries. the metadata and actula data are seperated and store in apache derby. so the burden on database is very less. hive process large tables easily because of distributive nature. and also you can compare the inner joins performance of oracle and hive. hive will gives you better performance always.